How to use TextField in an Android Glance Widget
I would like to create an Android Glance widget that allows for user input via TextField. However, TextField has dependencies that rely on FocusManager. In Glance, the CompositionLocal is not set, so I was going to use
CompositionLocalProvider(
          LocalFocusManager provides focusManager) { ... }

However, it is not clear how to instantiate a focusManager. LocalFocusManager isn't available in Glance.
I looked into instantiating FocusManager, but it is not clear from the Android codebase how to do this.

The FocusManager docs page says to just import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalFocusManager. Can you try that?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Glance is a wrapper around RemoteViews. RemoteViews does not offer text entry. Hence, Glance cannot support TextField().
